# What causes garbled window headers and blank menus (see pic), and can I resolve without hard reboot?

Tags: crash, macos

At random times, all the window headers and menus on my Mac become garbled or blank. See picture. The mouse remains responsive but I cannot select or even see any menus, I can't even reboot.  The only resolution I can find is a hard reboot (long press power button).

Has anyone seen this?  Is there a way to avoid it or fix it?

This is a 2017 Macbook Pro 13" running High Sierra 10.13.6[image]

Comment: Stuff like that is usually the GPU.  Start with Apple diagnostics by booting with the “D” key down

Comment: Are you using an external monitor? I have had the top menu bar blank on my laptop while the ext. monitor is fine. All I have done is move a window back to the laptop screen and all is well.

Comment: I am using an external monitor but the problem occurs on all monitors simultaneously.   Moving a window to the laptop screen doesn't change it.  Show in the pic is the Apple Menu on the external monitor but it looks the same if I open it on the built in screen.  I'll try the hardware diagnostics suggested by Doug.

Comment: I concur with @DougMasters - Also, boot in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  This will disable any 3rd party kexts and software for that boot.  If it goes away, then there's something conflicting.

Comment: Diag mode said everything normal.  Safe mode won't help solve this.  The problem happens once or twice a week, so I'd have to be in Safe mode for a day to expect to see the problem and a couple of weeks before I could say the problem does not occur in Safe Mode.   However, in Safe Mode, the microphone and speakers are missing, screen redraws are very slow and meetings in Teams or Zoom are impossible.  So I can't use the computer in Safe Mode for days or weeks.  Not sure how else I can diagnose this :(